# Storage slot for contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage

How many slots does storing a contract take?

Like for example:

```js
contract MyContract {
   MyContract2 x;

   //more code
}

contract MyContract2 {
   //some code
}
```

How many slots does "x" take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state variable of a contract holds the address of that contract. So from storage perspective it is equivalent to:

```typescript
contract MyContract {
   address x;
}
```

And the `address` is `20` bytes.